# Output of pow() function in C++ is not giving accurate answer

Tags: c++, pow

The user will give an integer input. I have to find the mod after squaring it. But when I give a big integer, `pow()` gives the wrong answer. How can I fix that?

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //ios_base:: sync_with_stdio(false);
    //cin.tie(NULL);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        long long n;
        cin >> n;

        long long sn = 0;
        sn = pow(n, 2);
        long long v = pow(10, 9) + 7;

        cout << sn % v << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `pow` works on floating point numbers, not integers, so you always have to deal with problems related to floating point precision, if you use `std::pow`

Comment: The `pow` function computes floating point numbers, so your integer are converted into floating point numbers. Floating point numbers can only store integers upto a given size accurately. `10^9` crosses that limit.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Just don't use pow. `sn=pow(n,2);` should be `sn=n*n;` and `long long v = pow(10,9)+7;` should be `int v = 1000000007;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, `pow` works on floating point numbers. Since you want to square integers, you're better off just multiplying them together using `sn = n*n`. If you use an `unsigned long long` you'll be able to exactly compute the square but only if this square is at most `+18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

Answer (score 0):

The trick to solve this problem is computing the modulus earlier. [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) offers some opportunities for this.

For this question note that `(a * b) % m == (a % m) * (b % m)`.

Moreover 1000000007^2 does still fit within a 64 bit int, so the result will at all times be small enough.

Hence the relevant part of the code could look as follows

```cpp
const int64_t m = 1000000007;
int64_t n;
cin>>n;

n = n % m;
int64_t sn = n * n;
sn = sn % m;

cout << sn << endl;
```